# How not add new data into database that has similar id with data in database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

So I am making a Project a in Windows Forms and what I have to do is to get data from Excel and display it in Datagridview. I am Uploading data on Sql Server and than I am sending it in DVG.Every Time I Upload data on Server I have to add new data to old data but I does not have datas in database with similar id. I have Code to add new data in sql Server but I donn't know how not to add new data, that have a similar id with data in sql. Has anyone idea how t do that ? Here is my Code:

```
SqlBulkCopy oSqlBulk = null;

            string excelFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            excelFilePath = Path.Combine(excelFilePath, label1.Text);
            OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFilePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");

            try
            {
                excelConn.Open();
                OleDbCommand excelComm = new OleDbCommand("SELECT *FROM [Sheet1$]", excelConn);

                OleDbDataReader excelreader = excelComm.ExecuteReader();

                using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-OETHK6U\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Intel_DB;Integrated Security=True"))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    oSqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
                    oSqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Intel_Data";
                    oSqlBulk.WriteToServer(excelreader);
                }
                label2.Text = "Data has been added into database";
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                label2.Text = "Data has not been added into database";
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                oSqlBulk.Close();
                oSqlBulk = null;
                excelConn.Close();
                excelConn = null;
            }
```

Comment: In this case if SQL server has auto identity on table `Intel_Data` and `Sheet1$` dont have identity then you should add one more column which will uniquely identify records in `Sheet1$` and then you can add filter string while fetching data from `Sheet1$` in `where` clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (not exists(select * from table where ID= @id))
insert into table(fields) values (values)
```

or you can set unique constraint in `ID` so if user add same id it will throw error where you have handle it..

Comment: I tried to set ID as Primary key but when I try to upload data on database  Winfows Form gives me following Message "Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The statement has benn terminated"

Comment: check this url https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx @dave1993

Comment: keep that and add in web.config `<add key="DBConnection" value="server=LocalHost;uid=sa;pwd=;database=DataBaseName;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200"/>`

Comment: you are getting that error because ur query is taking more than define time..if above code doesnot work use `<httpRuntime appRequestQueueLimit="100" executionTimeout="60000" />` instead of that in <system.web> in web.config..I have done `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151"/>` and its working in my project you can try any of them

Comment: web configuration file must be in "Project->Add New Item->Web Configuration" ?